# JS IE8, 7, 9 Error 'attr(..)' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, object, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, null

I want to show the box-shadow when div is expanded. I am adding a class which is having a box-shadow class in expanding div case. 
And it is working fine in all the browsers. 
Problem what I am facing is IE 8 is showing an error :- 'attr(...)' is null or not an object.

I need your help to fix this. Please suggest.

This is what I have done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
animatedcollapse.addDiv('navDrop', 'fade=0,speed=100,')
animatedcollapse.addDiv('needHelp', 'fade=10,speed=300,')
animatedcollapse.ontoggle=function($, divobj, state){ //fires each time a DIV is expanded/contracted
    //$: Access to jQuery
    //divobj: DOM reference to DIV being expanded/ collapsed. Use "divobj.id" to get its ID
    //state: "block" or "none", depending on state
    jkmegamenu.render($);
        if($(".needHelpBox").attr('class').indexOf("shadow") > 0)
    {
        $(".needHelpBox").attr('class',$(".needHelpBox").attr('class').replace("shadow",""));
    }
    else
    {
        $(".needHelpBox").addClass('shadow');
    }

}
animatedcollapse.init()
</script>
```

Please help..!
Thanks

Comment: What library(s) are you using? Prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery! Use the methods that are here for you:

```
var helpBox = $(".needHelpBox");
if(helpBox.hasClass('shadow')){
    helpBox.removeClass('shadow');
} else {
    helpBox.addClass('shadow');
}
```

Bergi's solution is even simpler as it takes advantage of the `toggleClass` method.

The problem you're facing might also be within the selector  `$(".needHelpBox")`
Are you sure the html element has the right class (needHelpBox) attribute?
And what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I used this as you told me.. its not workign for me. I think I am skipping something. I am not that good in JS and JQUERY. Can you please help me how can i use or implement the code you told me in my code I have mentioned above. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: No, those are not the jQuery methods to do this. Also, you should not execute `$(".needHelpBox")` twice

Comment: Well you're very right but if my solution didn't "work" I don't see how yours could better... The problem seems to be somewhere else.
Still, I edited my answer.

Comment: Armel Larcier, Bergi Thanks for your help :).. Armel Your code helped me and solved my issue :).. Thanks you so much ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use the [`toggleClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) (if you use jQuery):

```
$(".needHelpBox").toggleClass("shadow");
```

or the [`toggleClassName` method](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/toggleClassName/) (you use Prototype, which seems likelier when there is no `attr`):

```
$(".needHelpBox").toggleClassName("shadow");
```